# What are some important or compulsory tests to carryout on Android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, testing, integration-testing

What are some compulsory test you need to carryout on your application before it goes into production?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you are wondering what exactly you need to test before users see your application?
For me it is divided into two steps: **Logic** and **UI**.
Regarding the *ui*, you need to make sure that your application looks good on different screens and devices, that animations work correctly and views do not lose their positions ...etc
Regarding the *logic*, everything is a little more complicated, we write scripts to understand if the user will have difficulties with the application. For example, are errors displayed correctly if we receive them, does the application work offline and what exactly is available, do our functions and queries return what we want to get from them, and if not, again, do we inform the user about this.

Maybe if you tell us more about the specification of your application, we can help you even more.